# How to automate firefox with powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently doing the automation with power shell and I am stuck in the following problem ,
I have automated internet explorer with scripting in power shell,

But now i need to automate Firefox using this , i have searched and not able to track down , 
Is there any way or  is it possible to automate FF with power shell ....suggestions are required.

Comment: What exactly do you want to automate?

Comment: I need to automate the Firefox to perform some fuctions on my web Application Like Login and filling Forms .

Comment: Would it be possible to post an example of how you do this in Internet Explorer? Then someone can try to change it to work with Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://watin.org/ You can work with the watin.dll wich supports multiple browsers..

I started to use it because i needed a File Upload which comobject InternetExplorer.Application  can't do...

Little snippet to get you started:

```
$watin     = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( "c:\WatiN.Core.dll" ) 
$ie        = new-object WatiN.Core.IE("http://xyz.com") #Here you could load also Firefox with watin
$ie.TextField([watin.core.Find]::ByName("HF_Text1")).TypeText("Text1")
$ie.FileUpload([watin.core.Find]::ByName("HF_file")).Set("C:\text.txt") 
$ie.Button([watin.core.Find]::ByName("HF_Button")).Click()
$ie.WaitForComplete()
$ie.quit()
```

Note that you have to run Powershell in STA Mode when using WatiN (powershell.exe -sta)

Comment: The watin.org domain is gone. The most recent real snapshot on Wayback seems to be Dec 2016, http://web.archive.org/web/20161230004014/http://watin.org/. There is a project page on SourceForge, which last saw code activity in 2012, https://sourceforge.net/p/watin/code/1217/. There is a Gihub fork which has seen some activity https://github.com/fluentsharp/FluentSharp_Fork.WatiN