# Auto logging in to salesforce using PS on Chrome

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, internet-explorer, automation, salesforce

I have the following script for logging in to salesforce on IE.
I want to login using chrome or firefox.
If I need a completely new script I will use it.

```
$username = "username@domain.com" 
$password = "Mypassword"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://login.salesforce.com")
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
} 
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password"
$login = $ie.document.getElementsByClassName("button r4 wide primary") | Select-Object -first 1
$login.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **evil**, if you want systematic access and automation you should look into proper REST or SOAP API access, with OAuth2 flows. There's even a flow where you don't share password, the trust is established by signing a request with certificate that was earlier uploaded to SF and the user preauthorised...

This should never be part of any serious deliverable. If this gets hacked - your company / client can sue for damages.

If you really need it you can use simple GET like https://login.salesforce.com/?un=username@example.com&pw=hunter2, no need for fancy scripting. In Setup -> Login History you'll see that the method was GET instead of POST (submitting the real form). I don't think it's officially supported, they could change it anytime. It'd pass your password plaintext over the web...

Edit:
Check what your company signed. For example the Master Service Agreement
https://a.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/www/ocms-backup/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf

> (…)the Service or Content may not be accessed by more than that number
> of Users, (b) a User’s password may not be shared with any other
> individual(…)

Comment: I appreciate the help. I understand its a bad idea and the company has been informed about the dangers it has. Obviously they want to move forward in this project. I have tried that URL with my UN and PW and it doesnt work. It takes me to salesforce but doesnt input my information.

Comment: No errors in my login history. They don't even show up in the history. When I try it tells me to check my username and password. I know its correct because Ive triple checked.

Comment: If it doesn't show up at all you might be going to wrong org (sandbox username used against prod etc) or it genuinely doesn't recognise the username. You probably don't need but try to urlencode it, like swap @ with %40? Do you use normal Salesforce username and password or some Single Sign On?

Comment: Ive tried                                                                                    https://login.salesforce.com/?un='MyUsername@domain.com'&pw='MyPassword'              https://login.salesforce.com/?un='MyUsername%40domain.com'&pw='MyPassword'  https://companyname.salesforce.com/?un='MyUsername@domain.com'&pw='MyPassword'                                                       https://companyname.salesforce.com/?un='Myusername%40domain.com'&pw='MyPassword'                                                     I use a normal username (email) and password (whatever you set it at)

Comment: Your links include "%27" around username and before password. That's the single quote urlencoded. Is this your error, part of anonymisation for the comment or stackoverflow messing the links up? I really think you're making typos somewhere. And if you're using MyDomain versions it has to be companyname.my.salesforce.com. It really should "just work". What if you make a new Developer Edition?

Comment: My links include %27 because I added apostrophes in the link. I dont know how else to show you I dont have typos other than use my username and password. I get it to insert the UN and then it doesnt log me in. I paste the same password from the url into the pw box and it logs me in. The first link is exactly the response I get when its my username and password. I know im using the correct information. What do you mean by developer edition?

Comment: You can sign up for a free private Salesforce instance that has most features activated, "just" limited storage space. https://developer.salesforce.com/signup useful for prototyping or for example having your certifications and trailhead progress linked to it so if you ever leave current company - you can take your status with you.

Comment: Here you go, try copying whole https://login.salesforce.com/?un=corwin-amber@o2.pl.stack&pw=Um*kLkE38nj@}t~r and tell me what happens. You'll probably get stuck on the "unrecognised browser, please enter verification code" but that means the basic username + pass check passed. Give me an email address and I could create user for you in there

Comment: Cool, delete the comment to not leave your email in the wild. I've created your user. And I added both our IPs to Setup -> Network Access. Go ahead, open new incognito window or different browser, it should now let you in on my username without verification step

Comment: It worked. I was able to get into salesforce. Is it a setting in salesforce I need to get changed? Im copying exactly what you have except with my credentials to login and it wont work.

Comment: I've just signed up for this dev edition today and I didn't make any changes to it other than whitelisting 2 IPs & creating you :/ You can check setup audit trail. Does your password include special characters that need to be urlencoded? I see your login history has lots of "invalid password" so at least it recognises username...

Comment: I have !@# in my password. How would I urlencode them?

Comment: %21%40%23. There are lots of online try-it-yourself ones like https://www.urlencoder.org/ . Write it in the script like that. Or I'm not a PS guru but this looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548386/how-do-i-replace-spaces-with-20-in-powershell/37882097

Comment: Thank you! that urlencode worked! what an easy fix to such a pain in the butt. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You'll probably need to work on it bit more like make sure that user's password is set to never expire. Whitelist IP range for whole office network (VPN?) so people aren't hit by that email verification thing... It's still going to be fragile as hell but hey, I helped you shoot yourself in the foot ;)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: There's no built-in way to do what you're asking.

Let me preface this by saying that, in general, **trying to automate logins in this manner is a *really, really bad idea***. I cannot stress enough how dangerous this is from a security perspective. I would **strongly** recommend against attempting to write a Powershell script to automate a login in this manner unless it is done with a fake username and password for learning/test purposes.

That being said, IE has a rich COM interface - Chrome and Firefox, not so much. You will need to [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634603/running-com-objects-within-firefox-or-chrome) an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610558/how-to-automate-firefox-with-powershell) to enable the same functionality.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I understand its a bad idea and the company has been informed about the dangers it has. Obviously they want to move forward in this project. If I install the chrome extension would my script work without any changes? My project is to show a specific webpage of data from salesforce automatically. They want to be able for anyone to run the script and it to work. If there's an easy way todo this Id love to hear it.